# Как в SQLite динамическое количество строк сделать столбцами и по ним выполнить запрос?

Tags: sql, sqlite3

Например есть таблица продаж, в ней есть следующие поля: кто_продал, год_продажи и прочие.

Нужно сделать запрос который вернет:

| Кто продал | в 2020 | в 2021 | в 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Саша | 123 | 156 | 163 |
| Маша | 111 | 118 | 99 |
| Паша | 0 | 56 | 87 |
| Даша | 0 | 12 | 0 |

Количество столбцов и строк динамическое.

Comment: Столбцы получаются из секции SELECT, а стоки из количества данных. В чем проблема именно возникла в написании запроса?

Comment: Такие вещи гораздо удобнее делать в клиентском приложении, чем в sql

Answer (score 0):

Так как SQLite не поддерживает инструкцию pivot, придётся использовать разворот case'ом

```
SELECT
  кто_продал
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN год_продажи = 2020 THEN ... END) AS "в 2020"
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN год_продажи = 2021 THEN ... END) AS "в 2021"
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN год_продажи = 2022 THEN ... END) AS "в 2022"
FROM таблица_продаж
GROUP BY кто_продал
```

Агрегатную функцию выбрать по вкусу. SUM если нужна общая сумма, COUNT если количество. Вместо `...` подставить нужный столбец.

Так как строки с CASE у нас почти одинаковые, их можно генерировать динамически, достаточно написать цикл по всем годам, например, получив их SQL-запросом

```
SELECT DISTINCT год_продажи FROM таблица_продаж
```

Но генерировать запрос придётся клиентскому приложению. На чистом SQL это не сделать